# Jdbc: What happens to running statements on application exit?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Assume I have a long running statement, say `load data infile...`, and the Java application quits, what happens to the statement?

Will the statement finish? Will rollback? Will it die somewhere in the middle? Does it depend on configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JDBC database Connection Object is just a cursor to a database connection that is owned and managed by the database.

If the application exits without closing the connection properly, the database connection will be left unclosed (including all the running statements). This may result in database resources being wasted (until a timeout happens on the database side) or even memory leak.

Comment: Resource hogging is something else. This is a resource leak.